# Windows phone 7 How to create events to update UI

Tags: silverlight, events, windows-phone-7

Hi I'm making an app that when it launches makes a HttpWebRequest, receives some XML and puts it in a list. This code is in the Application_Launching method in App.xaml.cs . This list is then used in a listpicker on the first page of the app.

However because HttpWebRequest executes on a different thread the list is not populated when I assign it to to the Listpickers itemSource.

I've been told I should have an event that fires after the list is full and a listener on my  first page to populate the list when this happens. How would I declare this event and its listener?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpWebRequest and make AsyncCallback or use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class which has an event DownloadStringCompleted. [An example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/594e1422-3b69-4cd2-a09b-fb500d5eb1d8/).

Answer (score 0):

```
   public void GetXMLfromServer()
    {
        try
        {
            string url = "";//your url here 
            HttpWebRequest request =
        (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
            request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetXMLfromServerCompleted),
            request);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
    private void GetXMLfromServerCompleted(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        try
        {
            string resultString = "";
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
            using (StreamReader streamReader1 = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                resultString = streamReader1.ReadToEnd();
            }
            //**Put your code here to populate the list** 

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Ishti but can I listen for GetXMLfromServerCompleted to be completed on my Mainpage (where the listpicker is) and then assign the listpickers item source

Comment: you can pass a deligate to the GETXMLfromserver method and call the deligate in GetXMLfromServerCompleted.

Comment: Could you show me the code for that I've never used delegates before. I've got as far as declaring my delegate and event. 

public delegate void ListPopulatedOccuredHandler();
public event ListPopulatedOccuredHandler ListPopulatedOccured;

and invoking the event 

if (this.ListPopulatedOccured != null)
{
    this.ListPopulatedOccured.Invoke();
}